# How to cross-compile Qt applications for A13 Olinuxino (armv5) board?

Tags: qt, arm, qt-creator, cross-compiling

I am using A13 Olinuxino (armv5) board and QT Creator.

How can I cross compile my QT applications for that target platform?

Comment: Does Qt support your target platform?

Comment: What do you mean by support?

Comment: I mean if A13 Olinuxino (armv5) is listed among [the supported platforms](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/platform-details.html).

Comment: No, its not supported.

Comment: Then the answer to your question would be "You can't". Hm, but on the other hand, there's a video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v-ndT9fh3e0, that shows someone has succeeded, so may be it can be done.

Comment: What if I upload Qt libraries to target platform?

Comment: Try it, and see if it works. See this video - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v-ndT9fh3e0, may be you should ask a question from the uploader, how did he manage to make it work?

Comment: Also see http://olimex.wordpress.com/2013/07/12/embedded-gui-with-a13-olinuxino-lcd4-3ts-and-embedded-qt/ Apparently some guy has documented the entire process of setting up the environment, and cross-compiling for that board.

Comment: Sure, thank you! I will send message to him.

Comment: Hey, check this out, the guy who wrote the tutorial at http://olimex.wordpress.com/2013/07/12/embedded-gui-with-a13-olinuxino-lcd4-3ts-and-embedded-qt/ is also the uploader of the video - it's the same video that's playing on his page. So you should definitely read his tutorial.

Comment: I am reading it now, it is a good tutorial.

Comment: OK, I posted the synthesis of our discussion as an answer, you can accept it if the tutorial works out for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Nick Guthrie has managed to compile Qt applications for an A13 Olinuxino (armv5) board. There is [a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v-ndT9fh3e0&feature=youtu.be) showing a Qt application running on that board.

He talks about it in this [forum post](https://www.olimex.com/forum/index.php?topic=1595.0#msg7254).

Most importantly, he gives a link to a [fully configured cross-compiling environment](http://nickguthrie.com/embedd_gui/bin/A13-OlinuXino/debian_v2_20130713_touchscreen.image.gz), as a Debian image (I'm assuming it's a virtual machine with everything set up to work).

There is a tutorial on [compiling Qt for A13 Olinuxino (armv5) board](http://nickguthrie.com/embedd_gui/doc/) that he's made.